# ASP.NET Identity doesn't update Identity information on same request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

I am working on a single page application using AngularJS and ASP.NET Identity 2.  I log the user in and the cookie is set; however, when I check the Identity of the user on the same request, it shows it as blank and IsAuthenticated is false.  However, these are populated on subsequent requests.  I was hoping to send back to the UI whether or not the user was logged in on the same request.  Is this possible?

Code as requested (AngularJS makes AJAX post into WebAPI controller Login method)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    var result = await _securityService.Login(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password);
    if (!result)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("errorMessage", "Invalid username or password.");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    return Ok();
}

public async Task<bool> Login(string userName, string password, bool persistCookie = false)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
    if (user != null)
        await SignInAsync(user, persistCookie);
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}

private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    _authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {IsPersistent = isPersistent}, await CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie));
}

public Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentity(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
{
    return _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType);
}
```

Comment: Code would be helpful.

Comment: code added, hope it helps!  BTW, I though setting AuthenticationMode.Active might help in some form, but that didn't help any!

Comment: so if I am understanding this right, identity information will be blank unless the request contained a cookie (or token).  But I'd expect this to be set by the authentication manager when signing in?  Perhaps this is impossible?

Comment: What you are saying seems to be true but what is the use case, why do you want to check for authentication directly after you have authenticated?

Comment: because I am thinking it needs the cookie in the request to tell if a user is authenticated or not?  And since that request was initially anonymous, it wont pick it up until the next request?  I wanted to send back as confirmation, but I suppose the 200 OK should be sufficient?

Comment: Well you are free to send back confirmation if you want. After all if the call is successful you will authenticate the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't get a signed in identity until the next request because the call to SignIn is what's causing a cookie to be set on the response.  That cookie will turn into the identity on subsequent requests, but its too late to change your current request's identity.

Answer (score 2):

When using Owin authentication, the `AuthenticationManager.SignIn()` method barely sends a message to the cookie handler to set a cookie when the cookie handler gets to handle the request after the Web API Controller (see my blog post [Understanding the Owin External Authentication Pipeline](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/) for details).

But the `Login` method returns `true` if the login was successful and `false` if not, so you can use that information in the `Login` action to send back information. If you don't only want to know if the login succeeded or not, but also want the actual identity you can change `Login()` to return the user in case of successful login and `null` if failed.

Answer (score 0):

> I log the user in and the cookie is set; however, when I check the Identity of the user on the same request, it shows it as blank and IsAuthenticated is false.

[This is just a lack of knowledge on your part about how the ASP.Net pipeline works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx).

There is a fairly large pipeline of events that occur.  I'm pretty sure MVC runs in the [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest(v=vs.100).aspx) method.  This method is after the [AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest(v=vs.100).aspx) event and the [PostAuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest(v=vs.100).aspx) event.  This means that the entire ASP.Net authentication *framework* can never be updated during the ProcessRequest method.  This is why you'll see almost all system do a redirect afterwards, so that the next request has all the authentication (IIdentity, IPrincipal, IsAuthenticated, etc).

> I was hoping to send back to the UI whether or not the user was logged in on the same request. Is this possible?

How could the code not be able to?  The first request either authenticates them or not, whatever code is doing that knows if they are authenticated.

Comment: Redirects are done for quite different reasons. For example because the login page only serves as a login page or because they want to avoid resubmitting the data on F5

Comment: I probably do lack knowledge, and I'm not using MVC (WebAPI), so what I had said previously in my comment was correct.  Thanks for your reference.  Not sure what you mean by how could the code not to?  Yes, the user is authenticated, but as mentioned the cookie still gets set in that response, so a subsequent request would should identity as authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping to send back to the UI whether or not the user was logged in on the same request. Is this possible?

Yes. As said in other responses, you can.

I just want to cover the case when you are in the same request but outside the context where the SignIn took place.

Through Owin, you could use something like this extension method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the user was authenticated in the current request, or in a previous one
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsUserAuthenticated(this IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return true;

        if (null != context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant && null != context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity)
        {
            return context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        return false;
    }
```