# ASP.NET Identity and HTTP based services with API keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've seen a couple of posts like this one: [ASP.NET Identity doesn't update Identity information on same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661012/asp-net-identity-doesnt-update-identity-information-on-same-request)

They all recommend that a redirect should be used to get the correct claims identity.

I'm building a HTTP services using HMAC authentication (using custom HTTP headers). I've done it the proper way by creating my own authentication middleware and handler class. That design is really great.

However, forcing my users to do a pre-request for authentication and force them to manage the generated cookie is just plain maaaaaadness. Why can't it be attached to the request pipeline like in all previous versions of ASP.NET?

Am I forced to tell my users to manage cookies?